# Slow file transfer in one direction over MPLS

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, server-message-block, mpls

We are having an issue with file transfers over our MPLS.

Our setup:

```
Home Office <====== MPLS ======> Datacenter
VM Cluster                       VM Cluster
Windows 2008                     Windows 2008
```

### Via network Shares:

When transferring files from local folder on both PCs and Servers in the home office to the Datacenter we are averaging 177kbps.

When transferring files from local folder Servers in the Datacenter to the Home Office we are averaging 5mbps.

### Via FTP:

When Transferring files via FTP from local PCs and Servers in the home office to the Datacenter we are averaging 5mbps.

I didn't test FTP in the other direction.

Any help on where to start looking would be appreciated.

---

Update from questions below:
DC's are all Windows Server 2008

The Datacenter is aware of the issue, but all of their equipment tests out fine.

This has been happening since it was set up, the previous admin was working on correcting it when they left. No notes on their research were left behind.

Identical Firewalls and Routers in each location.

Updated to detail server hardware.
The Servers are all Windows Server 2008 running on VMWare.  I did test on a non VMware server in the datacenter and received similar results.

Comment: Did this problem just arise out of nowhere recently?  Has it been going on a while?  Have you contacted the network provider to have them check for issues?  Are there any routers/firewalls under your control in the path?

You should update your question with more information.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I updated my question.  Also, we do have full control over the above firewalls and routers.

Comment: Are the servers completely up-to-date with the latest Windows updates?  What about hardware/driver updates such as BIOS, network drivers, etc?  I have seen network speed issues in the past when network drivers were not up-to-date.

Comment: Yes, we went through all of our servers and devices and updated them.

Comment: Can you update the question to include some detail about the make(s) and model(s) of servers you have?

Comment: Are you sure you have just one MPLS link with your datacenter ? What about class of service on your MPLS, is it enable ?

Answer (score 0):

Are the Win2008 domain controllers? If so, writes will be issued with a rather slow 4KB-sized SMB packets, rather than the much more efficient 64KB-sized normally used.

When using 4KB SMB packets, the SMB/CIFS protocol become very latency limited. When pinging the datacenter from the remote office, what is the round trip time (rtt)?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Wouldn't the Win2008 issue affect transfers on both ends?  I have very good transfer speeds coming back from the datacenter, it's just getting there that is the main issue.  The RTT is averaging at 44ms.

Comment: Reads are always served with the larger 64KB-sized packets, data transfer from the datacenter (reads) will be significantly faster than transfer to the datacenter (writes). So, are the affected servers domain controllers?

Comment: No, none of the affected servers are DC's.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your servers are completely up-to-date with the latest Windows updates and hardware/drivers updates such as BIOS, network drivers, etc.